# How to put jQuery :gt() dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a jQuery `:gt()` selector which allows to select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

I can use it like this:

```
$(this).find('a:gt(30)');
```

The problem is that I'm using a var instead:

```
var opt = $("#div").text();
```

How do I set the `:gt()` selector next to the variable:

```
var opt = $("#div").text();

$(this).find(opt:gt(30));
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you're trying to select an element by index within a string?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't make any sense. I suppose you meant `$(this).find(opt + ":gt(30)")`; if `opt` has value of, for example, `"a"`

Comment: This is just an example...My code works, I just need to get the var next to :gt(). I cant image that this is not possible...

Comment: @Alexander Ofcourse it has a value....

Comment: @Youss, and what's the value? Any sample value?

Comment: @Youss, ah!? Did that answer your question?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov How does it matter??

Comment: @Alexander Yep, if you post it as answer I can accept

Comment: @Youss, it matters because if your variable contains for example the `foobar` value instead of a valid jQuery selector your code will not work.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov The question is not about my value...

Comment: @Youss, I was just trying to understand your question. Judging from the number of downvotes you got on your question I guess I am not the only one who didn't quite well understand it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov ok thanks (downvotes dont make sense..)

Comment: @Youss, I guess that downvotes are the result of lack of details in your question. For example you could have provided sample values for your variables which would have made it much more clear. But anyway, I am glad your question is now answered and the problem solved. I am just mentioning this for any possible questions you intend to ask in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use string concatenation.

```
$(this).find(opt + ":gt(30)")
```

If `opt` has a value of, for example, `"a"`. Then the expression `opt + ":gt(30)"` will evaluate to `"a:gt(30)"`.

You need to be careful that `opt` is a valid selector.

Comment: Thanks again. I set the value as var because it could be anything(a,span,p etc)